# GMSMapView (google map) GMSGeometryContainsLocation method is crashing in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, coordinates

Iam using this GMSGeometryContainsLocation() method in GMSMapView iOS (google map).

When i check current coordinate is under my GMSPolygon or not then its crashing.

```
 if (GMSGeometryContainsLocation(userLocation.coordinate, self.path, YES)) {

        NSLog(@"YES: you are in this polygon.");

    } else {

        NSLog(@"You do not appear to be in this polygon.");

    }
```

crashing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  Please help.

this is how am adding coordinates to path, and i can see all polygons in map.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < [[polygon  valueForKey:@"polygon_coordinates"] count]; i++){

                    [self.path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[[[polygon  valueForKey:@"polygon_coordinates"] objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:1] floatValue],[[[[polygon  valueForKey:@"polygon_coordinates"] objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:0] floatValue])];
                }



            GMSPolygon *rectangle = [GMSPolygon polygonWithPath:self.path];
            rectangle.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:0.4];
            rectangle.title = RESTRICTED_AREA_PICKUP;
            rectangle.map = self.mapView;
```

Comment: Could you please share the rest of this class? Perhaps **userLocation.coordinate** or **self.path** are nil?

Comment: both have values, i have checked that

Comment: Hard to debug any further without  more of the enclosing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind crash is , GMSMutablePath. I was using GMSMutablePath instead of GMSPath.

```
 if (GMSGeometryContainsLocation(userLocation.coordinate,(GMSPath *)self.path, NO)) {

        NSLog(@"YES: you are in this polygon.");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"You do not appear to be in this polygon.");

    }
```